# Como puedo hacer para validar que al ingresar algun correo solo se permita "gmail" para registrar y no lo permita con alguna otra

Tags: html, css

Este es el codigo que agrego

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <lable for="inputDescripcion">Correo</lable>
  <input asp-for="correo" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputDescripcion" placeholder="Escribe el Correo Electrónico" required>
  <div class="valid-feedback">
    Dato Ingresado
  </div>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    La descripción es un campo obligatorio.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Donde se ingresa el correo?

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tan solo quieres la validación usando HTML, y suponiendo que vas a someter al formulario usando las etiquetas `<form></form>` y un botón del tipo `type="submit"`, entonces puedes usar el atributo [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email) en el campo `<input>` que te permite aplicar un filtro de validación basado en una *expresión regular*.

En tu caso una posible expresión regular que te validará solo direcciones de correo de **gmail.com** sería esta:

```
pattern=".+@gmail\.com"
```

quedando de esta forma el campo input:

```
<input pattern=".+@gmail\.com" asp-for="correo" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputDescripcion" placeholder="Escribe el Correo Electrónico"  required >
```

Recuerda que esto solo sirve para validar dentro del HTML, pero un usuario avispado puede inspeccionar el código y modificar el pattern para saltarse esa validación, por lo tanto recuerda hacer también una segunda validación similar en tu backend donde vas a recibir los datos a nivel de servidor.  Esa validación a nivel de servidor sí que es segura.

### Ejemplo funcional completo:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputDescripcion">Correo</label>
    <input asp-for="correo" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputDescripcion" placeholder="Escribe el Correo Electrónico" required pattern=".+@gmail\.com">
    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">Solo se aceptan direcciones de correo de @gmail.com</div>
    <div class="valid-feedback">
      Dato Ingresado
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      La descripción es un campo obligatorio.
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
Enviar
</button>
</form>
```